# :hover state applied when angular view rendered

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I've come across a interesting bug. In an Angular 1.2.13 app on iOS Safari a `:hover` pseudo class is active when rendering back to a view. I'm using ui-router as well.

Here is the markup:

```
<ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked margin-2'>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref='mobileAboutEdit'>
          About
          <i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i>
      <enter code here/a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref='mobileNotificationsEdit'>
          Notifications
          <i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref='mobileAccountEdit'>
          Account
          <i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a ui-sref='mobileAdvancedEdit'>
          Advanced
          <i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i>
      </a>
    </li>
```

And controllers just for giggles:

```
.controller('UserEditCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $rootScope, metatags, UserService, UserAccountService, UnlinkAccountService, MetaTagsUpdateService, PasswordService, CookieService, SocketUtilsService, MessageService, ImageService, LogService, ImageUpdateService) {

    // Update metatags...
    MetaTagsUpdateService.update($state, $scope, 'user', {'<<username>>': $rootScope.loggedInUser});

    $scope.fileChanged = function(e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

        fileReader.onload = function() {
            $scope.imgSrc = this.result;
            $scope.$apply();
        };
    };

    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.imageCropStep = 1;
    };

    $scope.$watch('resultBlob', function(newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
            ImageService.save({image: $scope.result, object: 'user', id: $scope.user._id}, function(data) {
                LogService.info('Filenames saved:' + JSON.stringify(data));
                ImageUpdateService.updateUi('user');
                $state.go('user', {username: $rootScope.loggedInUser});
            }, function() {
                MessageService.addError('Error saving image.');
            });
        }
    });

    UserService.get({username: $rootScope.loggedInUser}, function(data) {
        $scope.user = data;
        SocketUtilsService.notifyUserMessages();
        $rootScope.$broadcast('user-account-details', {user: $scope.user});
    });

    $scope.save = function() {
        UserService.save($scope.user, function(data) {
            $state.go('user', {username: data.username});
            $scope.$emit('message', {level: 'info', message: 'Your profile has been updated.'});
        }, function(err) {
            MessageService.translateErrorMessage(err);
        });
    };

    $scope.saveAccountDetails = function(){
        var _user = $scope.user;
        UserAccountService.save({username: _user.username, email: _user.email, emailPublic: _user.emailPublic}, function(data){
            CookieService.setUsername(data.username, true);
            $state.go('user', {username: data.username});
            $scope.$emit('message', {level: 'info', message: 'Your account has been updated.'});
        }, function(err){
            MessageService.translateErrorMessage(err);
        });
    };

    $scope.addWebsite = function() {
        $scope.user.profile.contacts.push({name: 'url', value: ''});
    };

    $scope.removeWebsite = function(index) {
        $scope.user.profile.contacts.splice(index, 1);
    };
})

// Controllers in Advanced

.controller('PasswordCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, PasswordService, CookieService, MessageService) {

    $scope.passwordChanged = false;

    $scope.changePassword = function() {
        PasswordService.change($scope.newPassword, CookieService.getAuth(), function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                $state.go('user', {username: $rootScope.loggedInUser});
                $scope.$emit('message', {level: 'info', message: 'Password has been changed.'});
            } else {
                MessageService.translateErrorMessage(err);
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.isNewPasswordValid = function() {
        return !$scope.newPassword || $scope.newPassword.length < 6 || $scope.newPassword !== $scope.newPassword2;
    };
})
.controller('UnregisterCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $location, constants, CookieService, UnregisterService, MessageService, MetaTagsUpdateService) {

    // Update metatags...
    MetaTagsUpdateService.update($state, $scope, 'user', {'<<username>>': $rootScope.loggedInUser});

    $scope.confirmed = false;

    $scope.unregister = function() {
        UnregisterService.save(function() {
            MessageService.addMessage('Goodbye.');
            CookieService.removeAll();
            $location.path(constants.logoutPath);
        }, function() {
            MessageService.addError();
        });
    };

    $scope.confirm = function() {
        $scope.confirmed = true;
    };
});
```

Once I click into "Advanced" rendering that view and navigate back to menu view, the `:hover` state is active on the Notifications `<a>`. Here is a before and after the navigation and rendering:

[Before/After menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHpox.png)

I was able to hook up my phone and use the web inspector via Safari on my Macbook to determine it was the `:hover` state being activated when rendering back to the menu. And it is always just the Advanced/Notifications which causes this. So my question: why is `:hover` being applied in such a fashion? Since this is on a mobile device it is especially peculiar.

Answer (score 0):

As there are no hover states on mobile devices (you can't hover, only click), they have always caused trouble. Your options are either to remove hover state if you are primarily targeting mobile devices, or use the following common work around.

Firstly only set hover styles when there is a `.no-touch` class set.

```
<style>
  .no-touch .nav .nav-pills li a:hover {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
  }
</style>

<ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked margin-2'>
  <li>
    <a ui-sref='mobileAboutEdit'>
      About
      <i class='fa fa-chevron-right pull-right'></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `.no-touch` class is set using a simple javascript check that determines whether the browser exposes an `onTouchStart` event. If not, you can assert that you are not in a mobile environment.

```
if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
  document.documentElement.className += " no-touch";
}
```

https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/ provides a very informative write up about this problem, along with a detailed description of the noted work around.

Comment: I'd give you a +1 if I had more reputation because I didn't know this and it's good information. However, since what I was experiencing was confined to only one specific case and not everywhere a :hover state was applied, I used a media query for mobile screens in SCSS to `&:hover {background-color: transparent}`

Answer (score 0):

I like the info provided regarding `.no-touch` classes and `:hover` states on mobile. However, I inherited a large project that has default Bootstrap installed, a customized Bootstrap for the company installed, and then even more customized stylesheets trying to overwrite things in the previous two. Considering the issue I was seeing was so specific to one `.nav` and `li a` in the project, I just targeted it in SCSS with a media query as such:

```
ul.nav-stacked {
    // ...stuff
        a {
            //..stuff
            &:hover {
                background-color: rgba($gray-lighter, 0.3);
                @media (max-width: $screen-sm-min) {
                    &:hover {
                        background-color: transparent;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```